# knitr: Better Reproducibility of Knitted Code

Tags: r, variables, knitr, reproducible-research

Consider the file `foo.Rmd` following:

````
```{r foo, echo=yes}
print("Hello")
```
````

Note that the echoing of the chunk code is not constant, but depends on the value of the variable `yes` set outside `foo.Rmd`.
One can set the value of the knitting variable, e.g. `yes <- TRUE`, and then call `knit("foo.Rmd")`. However this makes the code fragile. In fact, if the calling code sets `yes` for its own needs, this will affect the knitting. For large/complex Rmd's it can be easy to have variable clashes: for example you  forget to set a variable for knitting, but this variable happens to be already defined for some reason, and you get unpredictable/wrong results.

A hypothetical solution is to explicitly set knitting variables via the `knit()` argument `envir`. That is:

```
e <- new.env()
e$yes <- TRUE
knit("foo.Rmd", envir=e)
```

`foo.Rmd` is now evaluated in the `e` environment, where `yes` has value `TRUE`.

In case  of multiple definitions there is no risk of clashes:

```
e <- new.env()
e$yes <- TRUE
yes <- FALSE
knit("foo.Rmd", envir=e)
```

The resulting markdown echoes the chunk, that is `yes <- FALSE` set in the parent environment does not affect the value explicitly set via `e` in chunk evaluations.

Now you might expect:

```
e <- new.env()
yes <- FALSE
knit("foo.Rmd", envir=e)
```

to produce an error such as `object 'yes' not found`. Unfortunately the knitting works using `yes <- FALSE` in the parent.

This is less problematic, but still, for a complex Rmd, you might forget to set some knitting variables and obtain wrong results.

Is there a way to allow only explicitly set variables during knitting?

Comment: what about using YAML parameters?

Comment: @sindri_baldur: For a single report I can change the Rmd header params. If I want to create several reports based on params, manually changing them, rather than setting them from the calling script, is time consuming and very prone to errors.

Comment: @sindri_baldur: Not yet tried, but one approach could be an initial setup chunk, exploring the environment passed to `envir` argument  in `knit()` by means of  `knit_global()` and raising a critical error if the expected variables are not found.